# How to provide a NuGet package that can work with multiple versions of a dependency

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have a class library that I want to make available via NuGet. It has a dependency on `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`. My library is compatible with versions > 4.0, which I have outlined in my `.nuspec` file.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0" />
</dependencies>
```

To develop my project I had to install `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` which I did via NuGet.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
```

This brought down version `5.2.3.0` which is not an issue until I publish my NuGet package, and try and use it with a application that has version `4.0.0.1` installed. I get the following error:-

```
Error   1   Assembly 'xxxxx, Version=0.0.2.22155, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

How can I build a NuGet package that will work with all versions of `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` that I stipulate in the `.nuspec` file?

Answer (score 0):

There was a breaking change in nuget 3.4. Make sure you are using v3.4 at least. You can do that by running "where nuget" on command line. 
According to v3.4 your dependency version tells nuget to use any version greater than or equal to v4.0 of Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc. 
So, yes, you have it right. 
You can find out more about versioning at http://docs.nuget.org/Create/Versioning